# How to add a property in ServiceNow which calls REST API of another application for look up?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I have an application (JAVA application running on tomcat) which has SACM and ITSM modules similar to servicenow. From my application I am calling servicenow APIs to look up data and create new records in servicenow. Does servicenow allow it vice versa?

Something like add a new property Associated CIs in Incident module, which will be a look up and on search it will make a rest call to my application get the result and show.

Is it possible ? If so how?

Comment: yes you can interact with any external system (retrieve data from your external app, post data to your app, a mix of both with some logic in between...) through outbound web services (example: REST messages)

Comment: I am using a mix of Client Script,Script Include and REST Message in the portal to achieve this. Is it the right way to do?

Comment: sounds O.K but but the architecture and the best practices are very specific to your application and depends on what you want to achieve so I can't say if this is the best way or not :)